# how to have modelchoicefield selection change value on page

Tags: django, django-templates

Before I do this with javascript, i wanted to check if it's possible to have a modelchoicefield/dropdown selection change a value on a page?

Is this possible in django?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. If you want to do some dynamic client/server business, Django won't do it without some HTTP request/response cycle.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with javascript. This seems to be the only way.